# Unresolved Reference when trying to switch Fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

**What am i doing wrong?**

I'm trying to do a simple Fragment switch when clicking on a button, but it keeps returning error on the line 46, to be more specific on **"v"** *when(v.id){*

**Error:
Unresolved reference: v**

My code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
   
    private lateinit var buttonHome: Button
    private lateinit var buttonConsoles: Button
    private lateinit var buttonGames: Button

    private lateinit var homeFragment: HomeFragment
    private lateinit var gameFragment: GameFragment
    private lateinit var consoleFragment: ConsoleFragment

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        buttonHome = findViewById(R.id.button_home)
       
        buttonHome.setOnClickListener (this)
        buttonConsoles = findViewById(R.id.button_consoles)
        buttonConsoles.setOnClickListener(this)
        buttonGames = findViewById(R.id.button_games)
        buttonGames.setOnClickListener(this)

        homeFragment = HomeFragment()
        gameFragment = GameFragment()
        consoleFragment = ConsoleFragment()
    }

    private fun setFragment(fragment: Fragment){
        val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_fragments, fragment)
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
    }

     //ERROR HERE
     override fun onClick(p0: View) {
        when(v.id){
            R.id.button_home -> {
                setFragment(homeFragment)
            }

            R.id.button_games -> {
                setFragment(gameFragment)
            }

            R.id.button_consoles -> {
                setFragment(consoleFragment)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've named your `View` parameter to your `onClick` method `p0`, not `v`. You'll need to either change it to `v` or refer to it via `p0.id`